# Copy Table from 1 database to Views

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that is in 1 database and I would like to copy it to the Views Database.  I'm getting an error.  Below are the errors

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Database 'Views' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
>
> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
> There is already an object named 'VW_vision_for_fire$' in the database.

Code

```
USE [Views]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VW_vision_for_fire$]
(
    [REM_GIS_ID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Location] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Owner Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Owner Address] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Owner Address 2] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Style] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Model] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Stories] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Grade] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Rooms Desc] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Bedrooms Desc] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Ext Wall 1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Roof Struct] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Roof Cover] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Int Wall 1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Heat Type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Air Cond Type] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Your table has a name beginning with `VW_` ....... that's just **asking** for confusion and clearly in violation of the *Principle of Least Surprise* !

Comment: As for the error, it's pretty clear; the database `Views` doesn't exist on the instance you are connected to.

Comment: Do all of your columns *really* need to be an `nvarchar(255)` as well? You are aware that there are other data types, and that the length can be defined, right?

Answer (score 0):

Seems fairly self-explanatory.  If you run these, do the database or table actually exist?

```
select * from sys.databases where [name]='views'
select * from sys.tables where [name]='VW_vision_for_fire$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in :

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE name = 'VW_vision_for_fire$')
```

Like this:

```
USE [Views]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE name = 'VW_vision_for_fire$')
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VW_vision_for_fire$]
(
    [REM_GIS_ID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Location] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Owner Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Owner Address] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Owner Address 2] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Style] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Model] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Stories] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Grade] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Rooms Desc] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Bedrooms Desc] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Ext Wall 1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Roof Struct] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Roof Cover] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Int Wall 1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Heat Type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Air Cond Type] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This way you will not receive an error and it will create the table, should it not exist.

If it does exist, it will ignore creating the table.

Please note that I do not have your data or DB to test, so I'm assuming the rest of your code is correct.